# How to avoid slot filling confusion when the same entity is used in more than one slot？

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

In the slot setting , I need to save date1 & date2 as context variables by two slot, let's me called it slot1 and slot2, and they all check for @sys-date
[image: ![enter image description here]

I have found a simple answer at [IBM document](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-slots#dialog-slots-avoid-slot-confusion).
However, it's an abstract description, I cannot really understand how to do so.

The document said the solution is to " Use slot found conditions that get clarification from the user about which date you are saving in a slot before you save it."

I think it is referring to edit this part (the below picture). But not knowing how

Think about this example sentence" I need to leave at $date2, oh, by the way, I'll be there from $date1"

In fact, the first shown date will be save as $date1 not $date2. What to fill in the "found" area?
Also, what's the effect of a response in slot1 (which should save $date1) like "Do you want to come at $date2?" It did not have a "save it as" (context) option in the edit area, neither an if/else condition setting.

I cannot find a video or step by step tutorial for this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See this step 5 in "[Improving a dialog node with slots](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-tutorial-slots-complex#tutorial-slots-complex-confirmation-slot)" in the IBM Watson Assistant documentation. Here, in substeps 11 and 12 the concept of "slot found conditions" is discussed.

Basically, you have to enable more options for the dialog node to see additional conditions. Now, replace that default condition `#True` by a custom check and add an additional question. Later, evaluate the answer to that question in order to set the context variable.